# Hy, problem mantaining big javascript code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have more than 1000 lines in a big jquery plugin, that is actually a big class, that inludes some others classes, but they have to be in the same file.

I inlcude a piece of code. If you have another way to simplify the code..
The actual problem is that i have a gallery with a lot of things, is dynamic with smart ajax data loading so it requires a lot of classes to use it properly and to cache the data.

```
(function($){
var TottysGallery = function(element, options, data){

    var Core = new function(){...};
    var Core2 = new function(){...};
    var Core3 = new function(){...};
    var Core = function(){...};
};
```

Comment: yes, how to manage and mantain a big code, with more than 1000 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The actual problem is that i have a gallery with a lot of things, is dynamic with smart ajax data loading so it requires a lot of classes to use it properly and to cache the data."

It almost sounds like you are trying to store data in JS... why not a SQL database or an XML file or some other means?

Comment: no lol the data is in a mysql database. the js load the data from db, then caches in temporary variables to dont load again if you come back again to see the same thing.